# How to check if JSON files are loaded correct

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have written a code that loads JSON files, I was able to test if they are loaded with:

```
with open(DATA_DIR+'/'+hs_filename, 'r') as file_data:
    data = json.load(file_data)
if not data:
    popup_critical("Error")
```

I want to do the same thing with try and except will this give the same result:

```
try:
    data = json.load(file_data)
except:
    popup_critical("Error")
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: No. The `data` could load entirely successfully, but be empty, in which case `not data` would trigger. That's different than failing to load the data because of, e.g., a syntax error in the JSON.